# I cannot send PUT data with html form

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, put

I have a form created in HTML

```
<form th:action="@{/forgotPassword}" th:object="${forgotPasswordDTO}" method="POST" role="form" id="forgotPasswordForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
...
```

and I want to send data to the controller

```
    @PutMapping("/forgotPassword")
    public ModelAndView recoverPassword(
            @ModelAttribute("forgotPasswordDTO") @Valid ForgotPasswordDTO forgotPasswordDTO,
            BindingResult result,
            ModelMap modelMap
    ) {
...
```

but `BindingResult` still returns errors to me because the fields of the `@ModelAttribute` object are null.

Can I send a PUT query using html form?

Comment: `method="POST"` ??

Comment: What 'method="POST'?

Comment: top line of your code

Comment: HTML can only take two GET and POST methods. However, it is said that there is a way to declare in input another method that can be used. But the problem is that it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot 1.5.6 then I did notice the Thymeleaf th:method="put", which you are emulating, seems to be broken. Replacing with th:method="post" and changing the controller method to a @PostMethod results in the form begin populated and validated correctly. Reverting back to version 1.5.4 corrected the problem for me. The same filters are being applied in both versions but the 1.5.6 version results in an empty form in the controller. I have checked two of my projects and they exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Spring boot 1.5.7 just came out and it seems to have corrected the problem.